# Need help finding an eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

I'm trying to compute the eigenvector of the following matrix:

$$
   A  =   \begin{bmatrix}
        0.3889 & 0.3456  \\
        0.3456 & 0.4044  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

where one of the eigenvalues is $\lambda=0.7423$. This example was taken from my course and I only have the solution:

$$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
        0.6991\\
        0.7150\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

The solution is correct since $A\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{v}$, but I don't understand how to find it. The system of equations I'd have to solve would be:

$$-0.3534v_{1}+0.3456v_{2}=0\\0.3456v_{1}-0.3379v_{2}=0$$

The solution is clearly $0$ for both components. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're  missing that there are solutions other than $v_1=v_2=0$

If $-.3534v_1+.3456v_2=0$, then $.3456v_2=.3534v_1$, or $v_2=1.022569v_1$. So $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\1.022569\end{matrix}\right)$ is a solution, as well as $\left(\begin{matrix}1*.6991\\1.022569*.6991\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}.6991\\.7149\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: They chose a solution with euclidean norm $1$ (one of the two unitary eigenvectors).